# how to repair flutter after interrupted upgrade?

Tags: flutter-upgrade

I executed flutter update but I accidentally performed a ctrl-C during the operation and the update was interrupted. Since I had a message with a java problem, I ran flutter -doctor telling me that the JDK is missing. I downloaded jdk 14.0.2 installed, and declared the path in the .profile .

Now flutter -doctor asks me to run 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' but I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. I had to kill terminal app because it was not showing any progress for long time.

After that when I started terminal again, I tried running command `flutter doctor` and it resumed completing upgrade (like downloading/installing files) and after that it showed status like installation version, status of XCode, Android Studio, Simulator/Emulator etc.

So, running `flutter doctor` worked for me.